# Setting hires bitmapData gets delay on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, air, bitmapdata

I have two images with two resolutions: HD(2500x1500px) & LD. I use LD in preview and HD in detailed view. When project loading, it stores loaded BitmapData into system memory as a bitmapData variables(lowres & hires as BitmapData). But when i call HD mode, it gets a 1-2 sec delay before HD image is displayed.
A bit of code:

```
var hires:BitmapData;
...
//when Loader complete
hires = e.currentTarget.content.bitmapData;
...
//Setting BD
this.BitmapData = hires;//--> Too Sloooooww
```

How can I get rid of the delay in the appointment of the HD bitmapData?

Comment: How much RAM is required by both bitmaps and how much RAM is built into the iPad? If the hires bitmap cannot be held in RAM, there will be a delay.